# Regex: How do you capture one group among multiple groups using regex? (in ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have two groups of text:

```
firstgroup
(some content)
endgroup


secondgroup
(some content)
endgroup
```

I'm trying to just capture the first group (not the second group). I'm using this regular expression:

```
firstgroup(.|\n)*endgroup
```

For some reason, that regular expressions selects both first group and second group (probably because it looks at the very last "endgroup" above). Is there a way to modify my regex such that I only select the first group (and not the second group)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a lazy quantifier

```
/firstgroup\n(.*?)\nendgroup/m
```

to end the group as soon as possible. See http://www.rubular.com/r/D6UkOnMYLj.

(And you could use the `/m` flag to make the `.` match new lines.)

Comment: Great! Thanks Kenny :) That was fast! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
string=<<EOF
firstgroup
(some content)
endgroup


secondgroup
(some content)
endgroup
EOF

puts string.split(/endgroup/)[0] + "endgroup"
```